# Search / Filter on primary key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I need to filter on a column, like `"SELECT * FROM code WHERE code='a';"` to get all code that starts with "`a`". That is: `"aa","ab","ac"`

```
CREATE TABLE codes (
    code text,
    PRIMARY KEY (CODE)
);
```

Do you know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Search (%% in sql) is not possible in cassandra.

The only way to do this efficiently is to use a full-text search engine like https://github.com/tjake/Solandra (Solr-on-cassandra).

Answer (score 0):

Datastax enterprise edition has integrated solr feature for such query. But still it has read performance hit.

Step 1) solr will search and get the list of keys
Step 2) these keys should traverse throw the entire cluster and get the data, again depends on CONSISTENCY LEVEL.

my recommendation is avoid such query, cassandra is not for that.